# Redirect_to not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a tutorial for building web app for placing ads (using Rails 4.2.6, but book was written about older version); and the idea of create action is to redirect user to new add page after it created. The suggested code from the book look this way:

```
def create
    @ad = Ad.new(ad_params)
    @ad.save
    redirect_to "/ads/#{ @ad.id }"
end
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't redirect anywhere - user get stucked on the congrats-page:

```
<h1>Ad created!</h1>
view your ad <a href="ads/<%= @ad.id %>">here</a>
```

What is the problem in my redirect code? What is the reason to use at one place #{@object}-construction, and at another - <%= @object %> ?

Comment: do you have a route defined for `/ads/#{ @ad.id }` ? what is your output for  `bundle exec rake routes | grep /ads` ?

Comment: @sa77, 
    `~/mebay $ bundle exec rake routes | grep /ads
    ads GET  /ads(.:format)        ads#index
    POST /ads(.:format)        ads#create
    new_ad GET  /ads/new(.:format)    ads#new
    ad GET  /ads/:id(.:format)    ads#show
    ads_new POST /ads/new(.:format)    ads#new
    ads_create POST /ads/create(.:format) ads#create
    GET  /ads(.:format)        ads#index
    GET  /ads/:id(.:format)    ads#show`

well, books says nothing about defining new route..

Comment: is it an ebook ? if yes, can you paste the link ?

Comment: nope, old-school paper book - Head First Rails, their working code is placed in http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfrails/ - chapter3 archive at the bottom of the page.
And if you get a e-copy of that book (i'm not sure i can use links to illegal content, but you can google it in couple of seconds) - you need to go to the page 128.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
def create
    @ad = Ad.new(ad_params)
    @ad.save
    redirect_to ads_path(@ad)
end
```

Comment: redirects now to ads_path (/ads/)- is there any way to redirect exactly to the /ads/@ad.id?

Comment: if you want it to send to the show action you can use redirect_to ad_path(@ad)